# JqueryUI, multiple ID's and else if statements on droppable, how do I get them to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a interface where I have 3 cards, that when dragged on a board individually change something about the view on the website. Its meant as a high fidelity prototype mock up.

I can however not get more than one card to work as intended. I cannot see why it does not work, Ive tried with multiple functions and now multiple else if statements, nothing works as intended

The HTML looks like this;

```
<div class="cholder">
    <div class="card" id="1">
        <div class="cardid">TURN ON LIGHTS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="2">
        <div class="cardid">TURN ON TV</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" id="3">
        <div class="cardid">OPEN DOOR</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the jquery as this;

```
$(".card").draggable({
    revert: function (event, ui) {

        $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        };
        return !event;
    }
});
$('.board').data('outside', 1).droppable({
    accept: '.card',
    out: function () {
        $(this).data('outside', 1);
    },
    over: function () {
        $(this).data('outside', 0);
    }
});

$('body').droppable({
    accept: '.card',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($('.board').data('outside') == 1) {
            if ($(this).is('#1')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".lamp").removeClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            } else if ($(this).is('#2')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".tv").removeClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            } else if ($(this).is('#3')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".door").removeClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            }
        } else if ($('.board').data('outside') == 0) {
            if ($(this).is('#1')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".lamp").addClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });;
            }
            if ($(this).is('#2')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".tv").addClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });;
            }
            if ($(this).is('#3')) {

                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".door").addClass('toggled');
                $(".main").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tco4q84t/3/)**
**[Other Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tco4q84t/3/)**

Comment: Looks like there's an extra set of closing characters at the end of the JS. What's not working, exactly? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I think thats just me.. had some trouble with the formatting, and this is only a part of my JS code... IntelliJ verifies the code fine.. and it runs with the draggable. No errors in the console either

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'originalPosition' of undefined`

Comment: Check the fiddle demo I added above and see if it's set up correctly.

Comment: Added a board to the fiddle.. They stop working when they pass, in the code I have they still work but they dont give the functions assigned in the else if statements

Comment: Whoops, sorry - done! :)

Comment: Made another fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/bscr7e1L/

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, my if's and accepted was wrong with the proper IDs;      accept: '#1, #2, #3', ---  if (ui.draggable.attr('id')=='1'

```
$('body').droppable({
    accept: '#1, #2, #3',
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($('.board').data('outside') == 1) {
            if (ui.draggable.attr('id')=='1') {
                audioElement.play();
                $('#my_content').toggle();
                $(".lamp").removeClass('toggled');
                $(".board").addClass('toggled').delay(1000).queue(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("toggled");
                    $(this).dequeue();
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure what you are trying to do exactly as the explanation and the fiddle is not clear, but from looking at your code, you can optimise it a lot better using `data-attributes` and the use of jQuery `toggleClass`

Examine your code and you will that all of your `if` conditions are to add some sort of class specific to each ID. Then simply save that class in a data attribute and retrieve that using jQuery. Now, all the other functions like toggling content are repeated and then you add/remove classes which can be done using the `toggleClass`

```
<div class="cholder">
    <div class="card" data-class="lamp" id="1">
        <div class="cardid">TURN ON LIGHTS</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card" data-class="tv" id="2">
        <div class="cardid">TURN ON TV</div>
    </div>
     .....
</div>
```

then all of your drop functions can be summarized in

```
$('#my_content').toggle();
$('".'+ $(this).attr('data-class') +'"').toggleClass('toggled');
 // i dont know why you need this but still you can use toggleClass
$(".main").toggleClass('toggled');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, greatly appreciated, but solved it same way.. See my answer down below :)

Comment: am glad you did :) i am suggesting another way to have your code and definitely much much shorter